# PHP: Clear/reset form which submits to self

Tags: php, forms, postback, reset

newb here.

Site url: http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc250.php#011

My student portal has two assignments on it which i've completed, both are forms and I'd like to be able to reset/clear them. I know that i could create a button to clear them that sends the user from 'http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc250.php#011' to 'http://school.max-o-matic.com/itc250.php' which would remove the anchor tag and that would reload the page clearing/resetting the forms in the process. But it would also require scrolling. I could also create a second anchor tag ('#011b') and have that in an invisible element and reload the page to that to keep/prevent scrolling but that seems like cheating/a dirty hack to me vs good programmatic practice.

I attempted to use this to reset the form ('echo '') but it doesn't seem to do anything. So i'm hoping someone can help me to find a good method to achieve my end goal which is to have a repeatable tool that will clear/reset the page so i can test out multiple scenarios without needing to scroll/rescroll continuously.

```
<?php

    //Constant never changes, 100% available everywhere- almost always simple datatypes (T or F, num, string)
    //define('THIS_PAGE', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);//shows webroot
    define('THIS_PAGE', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));//shows app root - gets name of the file basically

    define('TAX_RATE', .095); //current tax rate us => .095 => is 9.5%

    //echo THIS_PAGE;// shows this pagefile
    //VAR_DUMP - we love it cause we can see everything


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {//if data, do processing

        $purch01 = (float) $_POST['purchase01'];//float before floats data after
        $purch02 = (float) $_POST['purchase02'];//float before floats data after

        $subtotal = $purch01 + $purch02;

        $amountTax = TAX_RATE * $subtotal;

        $amountTotal = $amountTax + $subtotal;

        echo "<br /><br />";

        echo 'First Purchase: $' . round($purch01, 2) . '<br />';//standard
        echo 'First Purchase: $' . round($purch02, 2) . '<br />';//standard
        echo '<hr />';

        echo 'Subtotal before tax: $' . round($subtotal, 2) . '<br />';//standard
        echo 'Tax: $' . round($amountTax, 2) . '<br />';//standard
        echo '<hr />';

        echo 'Washington state tax: %' . TAX_RATE . '<br />';
        echo '<hr />';

        echo 'your purchase amount is $' . round($amountTotal, 2) . '<br /><br />';//risky double dollar sign


        /*
        echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($_POST); //shows everything the post knows
        echo '</pre>';
        */
        echo '<input type="reset" "reset the form." /><br /><br /><hr />';


    }else{//show Output

        echo
        '
            <form method="post" action="itc250.php#011">

                Enter Purchase Amount:
                <input type="text" name="purchase01" />
                <br />
                <br />

                Enter Purchase Amount:
                <input type="text" name="purchase02" />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        ';

    }//if you dont' need else, do a 'print and die statement' so if else happens you know else happened.

?>
```

Comment: To clear the form without refreshing the page use javascript.

Comment: Will that clear out the post data and bring back the input elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is as follows:

In the head I added:

```
<script> function reloadPage() { location.reload(); } </script>
```

In the body I added:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload page" onclick="reloadPage()">
```

This does what I want and it's something I can neatly apply over and over again so that's cool.

Answer (score 2):

reloading the page to clear the form is bad practice, and the functionality you want is built in:

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear" />
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: I tried this, but this doesn't appear to be able to clear/reset the from AFTER it's submitted (Posted back to itself). I use this for the before part, but it doesn't work once we have the echoed values returned.

Comment: @Chezshire according the logic posted above, if it's posted, the form should not even print, so i'm not clear on what behavior you're experiencing.  that said, the page reload is never going to be a good practice - you're forcing the client to download everything twice, the server to generate everything twice, etc.  if you'd like a pure JS solution, you might try something like $('form').find('input[type="text"]').val('');

Answer (score 1):

why don’t you do something simple like :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<input type="submit" name="reset" value="reset">
</form>
```

works and is clean, I don’t really see the "bad practice" in that ?

Comment: If you're referring to the "bad practice" mentioned by @momo, what he meant is: if a form can be cleared without a page reload, then why "torture" the user (+ unnecessarily exercise all the HTTP machinery) with a page reload?